# Apache rewrite url to seo friendly

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Before:

```
/review&blog_id=1
```

After:

```
/review/1

RewriteRule ^review/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*?)$ /review&blog_id=$1
```

Comment: Really `/review&blog_id=$1`? Shouldn't there be a query string? Do you mean `/review?blog_id=$1`?

Comment: @arco444 yes second variant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only after `/review/#number` then the following should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^review/([0-9]+) /review?blog_id=$1 [L]
```